# Scala imported functions not found

Tags: java, scala, maven, sbt

I recently started with Scala and I have some problems with the dependencies. I used both Maven's pom.xml and sbt build.sbt.

Going through the reference manual of sbt I already encounter problems importing scalatest.

I have my build.sbt in my project folder, then src/main/scala/Hello.scala and src/test/scala/HelloSpec.scala.

My build:

```
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.3"
ThisBuild / organization := "com.example"

lazy val hello = (project in file("."))
    .settings(
        name := "Hello",
        libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.2" % Test,
    )
```

And HelloSpec.scala:

```
import org.scalatest._

class HelloSpec extends FunSuite with DiagrammedAssertions {
    test("Hello should start with H") {
        assert("hello".startsWith("H"))
    }
}
```

Now when I enter the sbt shell and run test, it provides three errors:

- not found: type FunSuite
- not found: type DiagrammedAssertions
- not found: value test

Eventhough I have set my environmental variables (SCALA_HOME, JAVA_HOME), the strange thing is that the same thing happened also with Maven (not being able to use imported functions).

Comment: `org.scalatest.FunSuite` has been renamed in ScalaTest 3.2.0 to `import org.scalatest.funsuite.AnyFunSuite`. See https://www.scalatest.org/release_notes/3.2.0

Answer (score 0):

that's how it worked for me

```
import org.scalatest.funsuite._
import org.scalatest.diagrams._

class HelloSpec extends AnyFunSuite with Diagrams {
  test("Hello should start with H") {
    assert("Hello".startsWith("H"))
  }
}
```